# Cannot import dicom images in SPM

Tags: dicom, matlab-spm

I have some dicom images which SPM cannot import them, for each dcm file I see the below error:

S11956_I11604.dcm" does not seem to have positional information.

It seems my dcm files do not have DimensionIndexSequence field.
I tried to convert them to nii files by other tools such as dcm2nii. But they provide a single nii file for my whole DCM image, which during choosing frames, SPM see it as one frame. so I cannot specify any range of frames which is a need in "specify 1-st level".

please let me know if you have any suggestion.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this error can occur when your DICOM file is missing ImageOrientationPatient, ImagePositionPatient, or PixelSpacing. Without those, no program is going to be able to determine the correct geometry of your volume.

See https://github.com/canlab/spm12/blob/master/spm_dicom_convert.m#L1403 for the code error.

If you happen to have an Enhanced MR file, then it may be necessary to convert it into a series of legacy MR images (you could try MRIConvert or another tool to do so). I'm not that familiar with SPM, so I don't know if Enhanced MR is supported, but certainly a series of standard MR images would be.

Comment: thanks cneller, but I'm sure the dcm files have the three fileds you mentioned. The problem goes back to line 1395 which the output of read_DimOrg function is empty. this function needs DimensionIndexSequence field.

Comment: That attribute is required for Enhanced MR, so if it's missing then the DICOM source is technically invalid (https://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/enhanced-mr-image/multi-frame-dimension/00209221). Perhaps you can use a tool to manually add it, or perhaps there are tools that can convert to a series of standard MR images that are more tolerant of missing, required attributes.